# What is the maximum size of Sharepoint search API result I can have?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/pagination-for-large-result-sets) on Microsoft official docs, but it only talks about startRow. I want to know the size limitation of the Search result items.
Is it also 50,000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint search api is based on the sharepoint search. For sharepoint search limitation, please refer to this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search-limits